# Changing "It is strange that families adopt dogs but not a child." into passive voice

Tags: passive-voice, syntax, parallelism

When trying to convert this sentence into passive voice

> It is strange that families adopt dogs but not a child.

I found two confusing answers as follows..

> 1: It is strange that dogs but not a child are adopted by families.
>   2: It is strange that dogs are adopted by families but not a child.

Which one is appropriate?

Comment: It would be more pleasing to the ear if you used parallel plurals: "it is strange that dogs but not children are adopted by families."  The second sentence is ambiguous; it could be interpreted as: dogs are adopted by families but dogs are not adopted by a child.

Comment: The question is no doubt pleasing to ear. U tried. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

**"It is strange that families adopt dogs but not a child."** the OP's sentence.

The passive:

- It is strange that dogs but not a child are adopted by families.

Still **"a child"** vaguely referring to general plural meaning of **"children"** sounds odd here. I would recommend the following:

- It is strange that dogs but not children are adopted by families.